# Apache Tomcat server in netbeans 11

Tags: apache-http-server, java

I currently switched on netbeans 11.0 from netbeans 8 during installation i can find a option to add apache tomcate server . Then i tried to add server but i have to download server manually from net then i gave location of server too , and setup password and user name now,
issue is:- when i start server it ask for authentication and i even write correct password and username  the server doesnt start and show authentication dialog box again and again.
How can i make apache tomcat work in apache netbeans 11.0 manually?